# How to extract the value of a cell from Future[ResultSet]?

Tags: scala, cassandra, future

I get the data in the format, for example:

```
id
--
23
```

to Future[ResultSet].

The code to serve the same purpose without using Async is shown below.

```
{
var last_seen_time: Long = 0
    try {
      val results: ResultSet = session.execute(query)
      last_seen_time = results.one().getLong(0) * 1000
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable => println("Error occurred in executing the query:" +
        "Possible cause device not started sending data.")
    }
    println(s"current_time = $current_time")
    println(s"message_post_interval = $message_post_interval")
    println(s"last_seen_time = $last_seen_time")

    if (current_time.toLong - message_post_interval.toLong <= last_seen_time)
      true
    else
      false
}
```

How to perform the same action with:

```
val results: Future[ResultSet] = session.executeAsync(query)
```

Comment: You got the error when you did what ?

Comment: it is not an error, it's an object, its' class and hashcode...

Answer (score 1):

You can extract result using `onComplete` callback of `Future`

```
val result : Future[ResultSet] = ...

result.map {r => r.one().getInt(0)} onComplete {
    case Success(v) =>
        println(s"Id = $v")
    case Failure(e) =>
        e.printStackTrace()    
}
```

or you can wait until it is executed

```
val fut = result.map {r => r.one().getInt(0)}
val id = Await.result(fut, 10 seconds)
id
```

Comment: Thank you. Which is the 'seconds' in val id = Await.result(fut, 10 seconds)

Comment: it is Duration class instance. Just add `import scala.concurrent.duration._` to your imports

Comment: In the first method, how can we take value (v) and assign it to another variable so that I can use it for other tasks? @maksim07

Comment: why do you want to assign it ? you can use Future[Int] in another tasks. For instance when you need it you can either use onComplete or you can also chain consequent tasks using andThen combinator:

    val idFut = result.map {r => r.one().getInt(0)}
    val chain = idFut andThen { id => task1(id) } andThen {task2(id)}

    chain.onComplete {...}

Comment: also you might want to read more about futures and promises in [this tutorial](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Comment: ok. I need to assign the value to execute another function, whose output is the output of the function which holds all these.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101779/discussion-between-gkvm-and-maksim07).